# If the first derivative of a piece wisely defined function is continuos at breaking point, can I write it as a single function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^q$ be a piece wisely defined
>   function, defined as
>
> $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
>        g(x,y) & ;(x,y) \not = (0,0)  \\
>        0 & ;(x,y)=(0,0) \\ \end{cases}.$$

Normally, I would have to write $f_x$ again piece wisely, but if I know that $f_x$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, can I write as a single(not-piecewisely-defined) function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a single expression is able to represent a function over a whole domain, there is no need to decompose it piecewise, whatever it is.